# $animate.enter() on element of custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to use $animate.enter() inside of my custom directive, to show/hide the same element that the directive is defined on, like below but it's not working.  The "leave" function works just fine.

Thoughts?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);

myApp.directive('hideMe', function($animate, $timeout){
    function fnLink(scope, element, attrs){ 
        $timeout(function(){
           $animate.leave(element);
        }, 2000);

        $timeout(function(){
           $animate.enter(element, element.parent());
        }, 5000);
     };

    return {        
        link: fnLink
    };
});
```

[EDIT]
Here's a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/6P6qM/

Comment: 1.2.18 in my case.  It doesn't look like that breaking change applies.  The behavior they describe is exactly what I want, and the fix they supply doesn't help anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `console.log()` just before the `$animate.enter()` method will show you that `element.parent()` is empty, which is normal, since the element was previously detached from the DOM by the `$animate.leave()` method.

The solution is to save the parent before to detach the element. Don't forget to open your console next time!

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);

myApp.directive('hideMe', function($animate, $timeout){
    function fnLink(scope, element, attrs){ 
        var parent = element.parent();
        $timeout(function(){
           $animate.leave(element);
        }, 2000);

        $timeout(function(){
           $animate.enter(element, parent);
        }, 5000);
     };

    return {        
        link: fnLink
    };
});
```